# Div Expandsion on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions

I was wondering if anyone can give me some insight on javascript/jquery for div expansion. In the JSFiddle you will find:

- Four black divs:

  ```
  .first_box {
  width: 142px;
  height: 142px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  background-color: black;
  }
  ```
- A unique hover color for each div:

  ```
  .first_box:hover {
  width: 142px;
  height: 142px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  background-color: green;
  }
  ```

So my question is:

What can I use so that when a div is clicked, it expands to the size of the four divs (289 X 289)?

The expanded div will then be filled with unique content.

Thank you!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SXfeG/1/

Comment: Do you want to hide the other 3 divs when one of them is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use absolute positionning, you can add some CSS like that :

```
.div-clicked {
    width: 289px !important ;
    height: 289px !important ;
    margin-top: 0 !important ;
    margin-left: 0 !important ;
    z-index: 400 ;
}

div {
    transition: all 1s ; // To add transition effect
}
```

And then, with jQuery, you can toggle 'clicked' class simply by using :

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) { $(this).toggleClass('clicked') ; })
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/85QFN/

Comment: That is Awesome!! thank you for this. Is there a way to make the retract above the other divs? (Not behind them)

Comment: @user3087325 On Chrome v34 the div is still above when retracted. It looks like some browser do not support the transition effect on `z-index` property... I think the only way to deal with that is to deal with the transition manually with JS timeout... See http://jsfiddle.net/eD56Y/ Maybe there is a better way of doing this...

Comment: That looks really smooth on Firefox, thanks. Can I place different content in each box when they are expanded? Would maybe hide/show work for this?

Comment: @user3087325 Yes, just put 2 divs in each div, one with `display: none ` by default, and switch with  hide / show or fadeIn / fadeOut when you click.

Comment: When I import this to my webpage, the div that houses the square div is the one that ends up received the click function. Is there a way to change the javascript so it's not 'div' in the first line?

Comment: @user3087325 Yes, just add a class to your div like `box` and change `$('div')` to `$('.box')`, see jQuery selector documentation for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Upvotes for you! (i dont have enough rep though)

Comment: Could you help me out on the comment above about the 2 divs in each div?